# After I updated minecraft to 1.8.4 a lot of my stuff is missing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After I updated minecraft to 1.8.4 a lot of my stuff is missing. My tower is gone and in some spots land is over where road was. Even a village is missing half of some of the houses like they are literally half of a house where there used to be a whole house. I don't know what to do. Everything I had was in that tower. Now I have nothing. I don't even want to play anymore because I am so mad

Comment: Sounds like chunk corruption. Do you have a backup of the world?

Comment: If you're using Windows, you may be able to use file history. I know it's avaliable in W10, don't know about other versions.

Comment: If you have a backup of your world, then you may be able to restore it.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds as though the chunks became corrupted, this is a part of the game that you have to put up with. It you open to LAN with cheats enabled you can use `/give` commands to get items back.